# @SessionTarget,hibernate session is null

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, struts2, tiles

I am building a simple **MVC** app using **java**,**struts2**,**hibernate**.I create structure of app using tiles.I want hibernate create tables to continue to my next task.
I beleive,i have a **missunderstaning** on importing JARS to my app and their correct version.When i try to insert data,hibernate does not create user table and tell me that **session is null**.

Here it is my code and imported jars.

Thanks you!

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
         <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/development</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">dothebest</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <!-- <mapping class="com.SchoolManagement.domain.Address" /> -->
        <mapping class="com.SchoolManagement.domain.User" />
    </session-factory>


</hibernate-configuration>
```

struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default,struts-default">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>

        <action name="home" method="home" class="com.SchoolManagement.action.BaseAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">home</result>
        </action>
        <action name="training" method="training" class="com.SchoolManagement.action.BaseAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">training</result>
        </action>
         <action name="contact" method="contact" class="com.SchoolManagement.action.BaseAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">contact</result>
        </action>
        <action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.SchoolManagement.action.UserAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">listmyUser</result>
        </action>
        <action name="saveOrUpdateUser" method="saveOrUpdate" class="com.SchoolManagement.action.UserAction">
            <result name="success" type="tiles">listmyUser</result>
        </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

UserAction.java

```
package com.SchoolManagement.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.SchoolManagement.domain.User;
import com.SchoolManagement.service.UserService;
import com.SchoolManagement.service.UserServiceImpl;

public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6659925652584240539L;

    private User user = new User();
    private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    private UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();



    @Override
    public User getModel() {
        return user;
    }
    /**
     * To save or update user.
     * @return String
     */
    public String saveOrUpdate()
    {   
        userService.saveOrUpdateUser(user);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String list()
    {
        userList = userService.listUser();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<User> getUserList() {
        return userList;
    }

    public void setUserList(List<User> userList) {
        this.userList = userList;
    }


}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
package com.SchoolManagement.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.SchoolManagement.domain.User;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.SessionTarget;
import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.TransactionTarget;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @SessionTarget
    Session session;

    @TransactionTarget
    Transaction transaction;




    /**
     * Used to save or update a user.
     */
    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
        try {
            session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used to list all the users.
     */

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<User> listUser() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<User> userList = null;
        System.out.println("1");
        try {
            System.out.println("2");    
            userList = session.createQuery("from User").list();
            System.out.println("3");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userList;
    }

    }
```

listUser.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Page</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">

     <s:form action="saveOrUpdateUser">
        <s:push value="user">
            <s:hidden name="id" />
            <s:textfield name="name" label="User Name" />
            <s:textfield name="email" label="Email" />
            <s:submit />
        </s:push>
    </s:form> 


    <s:if test="userList.size() > 0">
        <div class="content">
        <table class="userTable" cellpadding="5px">
            <tr class="even">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <s:iterator value="userList" status="userStatus">
                <tr
                    class="<s:if test="#userStatus.odd == true ">odd</s:if> <s:else>even</s:else>">
                    <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
                    <td><s:property value="email" /></td>
                    <td>
                    <s:url id="editURL" action="editUser">
                        <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
                    </s:url>
                    <s:a href="%{editURL}">Edit</s:a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <s:url id="deleteURL" action="deleteUser">
                        <s:param name="id" value="%{id}"></s:param>
                    </s:url>
                    <s:a href="%{deleteURL}">Delete</s:a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </table>
        </div>
    </s:if>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here it is my jars

[image: jars_1]

[image: jars_2]

And here it is error:

[image]

Comment: It appears you're not using Maven to control your transitive dependencies; I'd encourage you not to do that. And while it may be on purpose (i.e., a mixed S1/S2 app), you seem to have a bunch of S1 jars in there. In any case, I wouldn't recommend mixing versions of S2 jars.

Comment: @DaveNewton You are absolutely right.Here it is my situation.First i was trying to build app with maven because i knew that maven will solve me problem of mixing and compability of JARS that is important for a project.But i am not familiar with maven and integrate to maven GAE or Apache Tomcat web server.It is a school project and my time is limited.So i decied to get the risk of importing Jars manually and build the app this way.Task on app is going well for me at this moment.My big fear it is that app lately will give me an error with those much jars i have imported.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hibernate core Session and Transaction injection capability, we need to use `basicStackHibernate` interceptor.

So add `<interceptor-ref name="basicStackHibernate" />` into your action:

```
<action name="listUser" method="list" class="com.SchoolManagement.action.UserAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStackHibernate" />
    <result name="success" type="tiles">listmyUser</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend @Spara.You saved me!Thanks!